# How to buy particular products without login in drupal commerce

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-commerce

I am new working in drupal-commerce module .Currently the system I have is that a logged in user should buy products from my site but there are two particular product I need to my users buy without doing any login . Is it possible in drupal-commerce ? My english is not good so if anyone have any query regarding my question please ask me.

Please help me if there is any solution to this .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Purchasing without creating accounts? It is possible.

It is possible to purchase products without creating an account.

By default anonymous users aren't permitted to complete the checkout process. What you need is grant them the *Access checkout* permission. Changing this permission is really easy:

1. From `/admin`, click on the *People* link, then *Permissions*
2. Under the *Checkout* section, grant the *Access checkout* permission to anonymous users
3. Click *Save permissions*.

Now anonymous users can use checkouts.

---

### How to setup your site to always be anonymous

There is another way to accomplish this, however it is more complicated and possibly you don't want this, I'm just sharing if so.

Users on your page don't have to be logged in (authenticated) or anonymous. To setup your site to always be anonymous, you have to disable only two rules.

The rules can be found by going to the *Store Configuration* screen and selecting *Checkout Settings* and then selecting *Checkout Rules*.

- Assign an anonymous order to a pre-existing user
- Create a new account for an anonymous order

Disabling these rules mean the users can't login to see their *Orders*, however it has no side affect  to being able to purchase items.

If you want to read more about this, check out [this](https://drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/checkout-anonymous-vs-authenticated) page.

Hope that helps